# Invalid request on client.request_airdrop()

Tags: web3.js, python, devnet, solana-py

**CODE:**

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.keypair import Keypair

LAMPORT_PER_SOL = 1000000000
client = Client("https://rpc.ankr.com/solana_devnet")
wallet = Keypair.generate()
print (wallet.public_key)
airdrop = client.request_airdrop(wallet.public_key, 1 * LAMPORT_PER_SOL)
print (airdrop)
```

The `request_airdrop` parameters are:

```
(method) def request_airdrop(
    pubkey: PublicKey | str,
    lamports: int,
    commitment: Commitment | None = None
) -> RPCResponse
```

It seems my parameters are correct, however, I'm getting the following error message:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'error': {'code': -32600, 'message': 'Invalid request'}, 'id': 1}
```

Comment: This is a problem with the Ankr rpc, switching the rpc to Alchemy fixed the issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we didn't learn what the root problem was, or what about switching to a new RPC solved it.